# Biber & Biblatex error after update

Tags: biblatex, biber

Here is the log I get. Biblatex docs says is version 3.17 but in error log says is 3.16

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.17
INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'
INFO - Reading 'main.bcf'
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.7, expected version 3.8.
This means that your biber (2.17) and biblatex (3.16) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
INFO - ERRORS: 1
Biber error: [494] Utils.pm:409> ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.7, expected version 3.8.
Latexmk: Found biber source file(s) [main.bcf]
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of *latex:
    Latex failed to resolve 8 reference(s)
    Latex failed to resolve 184 citation(s)
```

Comment: I uninstalled both biblatex & biber from MikTeX and reinstall again. Same error. In log I have this `Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'romanian'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'romanian.lbx' found.
(C:/Users/patrick/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/romanian
.lbx
File: romanian.lbx 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
C:/Users/patrick/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/romanian.l
bx:603: Package xkeyval Error: `langromanian' undefined in families `blx@lbx'.
See the xkeyval package documentation for expl
`

Comment: I don't get any such error. Compile the example file from https://gist.github.com/moewew/269f1922474a60192396c15f78b4a5cd and upload the complete `.log` file to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/. Hrmmm, note that your `biblatex` says it is `biblatex` v3.16. So either you got a bad mirror on the update that still serves the old version (try again in a few hours) or you have a local installation of `biblatex.sty` that takes precedence.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/HPJLzkaJ  here is the log. I suspect it is about mirrors

Comment: Yeah, the log definitely says you still have `biblatex` 3.16 even though the path looks like it would be the normal install path (so no local `biblatex.sty`). You have a local `romanian.lbx` that is incompatible with your `biblatex` in `C:/Users/patrick/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/`. Delete that `romanian.lbx` and try to update `biblatex` again in a few hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the `.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf` file of your project and recompile.

If that resolves the error then the problem was just caused by an old auxiliary file (presumably you ran Biber before you ran LaTeX, so that LaTeX could not update the auxiliary files to the new version before Biber got to see them).

If the error persists, you have not updated your TeX system completely. In that case you need to make sure that you update both Biber and `biblatex`. See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864) and [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864).

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was more than just a matter of clearing away some auxiliary files. My TeX installation is done via Homebrew (`brew install texlive`) and I believe there's a [longstanding issue](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/3003) of the Biber distributed with that not being compatible with the Biblatex package.

What fixed the issue for me was doing a `brew install biber` separately. This pushed my Biber up from v2.12 to v2.19, and this turned out to be enough.